# SQL server: How do i get the date of previous Saturday

Tags: sql-server-2008, datetime

I need to filter a table from last Saturday 7pm to now. How do i do that?

The column i'm filtering is of dateTime2(0) format?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This expression will always give you the previous Saturday at 7pm, independent of your `DATEFIRST` setting:

```
select DATEADD(week,
       DATEDIFF(week,'19000101',CURRENT_TIMESTAMP),'1899-12-30T19:00:00')
```

If it's run on a Saturday, it'll give you the previous Saturday.

Comment: To next, increment 1 week in DATEDIFF. Ex: `select DATEADD(week,
       DATEDIFF(week,'19000101',CURRENT_TIMESTAMP) + 1,'1899-12-30T19:00:00')`

Answer (score 1):

`SELECT * From TableName Where MyDate >= DATEADD(HH,19, DATEADD(DAY, (DATEDIFF(DAY, '19000106', GetDate()) - 1) / 7 * 7, '19000106'))`

Comment: Thanks, works a charm. I marked the other reply as answer as i found it more succinct (or at least understandable which is a comment on my bad sql skills as opposed to yours good sir). thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that your criteria of "last Saturday 7pm" is a constant...

```
SELECT T.*
FROM Table T
WHERE T.dtDate >= CONVERT(DATETIME, '2013-10-05 19:00')
```

Comment: To unambiguously give a date and time, you should use `T` as a separator rather than space, and specify the seconds: `set dateformat dmy;
select MONTH(CONVERT(DATETIME, '2013-10-05 19:00'))` produces 5, not 10. Using `'2013-10-05T19:00:00'` instead will produce 10 no matter what date settings are in effect

Comment: No Last sat 7pm is not a constant.